# Unable to verfiy Google oAuth JWT in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, jwt, google-oauth

I'm trying to verify JWT token manually but I cloudn't do. Here is my code

```cs
 public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleJWT(string jwt, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwt))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SignUpEmail");
            }


            var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = "accounts.google.com",
                ValidAudience = "XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret")),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            handler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            var user = handler.ValidateToken(jwt, parameters, out var _);


            return View();

        }
```

It shows this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:
```

I'm not sure Issuer or Audience is right?

Comment: I have no experience with google oauth, but you got a `SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException` and I really doubt that this `IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret"))` is a valid setup for a google oAuth token.

Comment: You may be right but I cloudn't find correct setup.

Comment: try googling for "google oauth verify token", google documentation or here on SO, click on the `google-oauth2` tag under your question.

Comment: I have been doing that for two days. But I cloudn't find correct answer. But thanx I'll do that again.